# How to convert only letters to uppercase from string php?

Tags: php

I want to convert from :

`a12b89` to `A12B89`.

I tried with strtoupper but it's not working. Is that function only if I have letters without numbers?
Thanks.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Show your code - we can't guess what you did. `strtoupper` is the function you need. Seriously - "It's not working" doesn't give us any clues.

Comment: No, `strtoupper` [will work](http://viper-7.com/A5AYg2).

Comment: **strtoupper** should do the job, just do : **var_dump(strtoupper('a12b89');**

Comment: Maybe you need `mb_strtoupper` instead?

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski: That should give unexpected `;` :)

Comment: not much you could do wrong, I mean `<?php echo strtoupper("a12b89"); ?>`

Comment: Oh, my mistake something different was a problem.
Sorry guys

Comment: @Shubham, Yeah, saw it after edit permission disappeared :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "a12b89";
echo strtoupper($a);
```